# Is it possible to pass con.setAutoCommit(false); to method in Java?

Tags: java

In the below code I want that if there is problem in sending any data to database then nothing will be store in the database. But I strictly want to use con.setAutoCommit(false); in my main function and then want to pass it to adddetails() and finally when adddetails() gets over then I want to commit in the main function.

Please help.

```
class addData
{

    boolean adddetails(Connection con, String s1,String s2)
    {
    try{
    PreparedStatement ptsd = con.prepareStatement("insert into x values (?,?)");
    ptsd.setString(1,s1);
    ptsd.setString(2,s2);
    ptsd.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement ptsd1 = con.prepareStatement("insert into x values (?,?)");
    //ptsd1.setString(1,s1);
    ptsd1.setString(2,s2);
    ptsd1.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;    
    }   
}

public class check {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try{
        JDBCMySQLConnect jmsc = new JDBCMySQLConnect();
        Connection con = jmsc.createConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false); ////////////////////
        addData a =  new addData();
        a.adddetails(con, "77","77");
        con.commit(); ///////////////////
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have your `adddetails` method return true if everything is ok, false otherwise. Then in your main, depending on this result, do a commit or a rollback .

Comment: Or rather don't catch `Exception` and let the calling method handle the catch (and rollback or commit).

Comment: Never (well, extremely rarely) catch an exception and continue as if nothing went wrong. Let the exception pass back up to the caller. Alternatively, what is the purpose of `adddetails()` having a boolean return value? Make it return false on error, so caller can roll back? Nah, best to let exception cascade.